# Gas compression

Tags: volume

I have a meter cubed volume of gas, what formulae do I need to calculate the space required for the gas when compressed at a variable psi/bar.

Not important at this time, but how would I allow for different densities of gas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want pressure and you have volume, you can use [Boyle's Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle%27s_law), which states$p_1*v_1=p_2*v_2$. In other words, if you know the volume $v_1$ and pressure $p_1$ at one time, you can solve for $v_2$ if you know $p_2$ and vice versa. You can also use the [Ideal Gas Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law), $PV=nRT$.